# `error instanceof MyError` returning different values

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

In my application, the expression `error instanceof NotFoundError` sometimes returns true and sometimes false, even though `error` is an instance of `NotFoundError` in each case.

Specifically I have the following code:

```
// apiClient.js
class HttpError {}

export class NotFoundError extends HttpError {}

export class UnauthorizedError extends HttpError {}


// Foo.jsx
import { NotFoundError } from 'apiClient';

function Foo({
  errors,
  ...
}) {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    const error = errors[0];
    console.log([error, error instanceof NotFoundError]);
    if (error instanceof UnauthorizedError) {
      return (...);
    } else if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
      return (...);
    } else {
      return (...);
    }
  }
}
```

I observed the behavior by logging the value of `error` and `error instanceof NotFoundError`, and seeing the second value change.

I don't understand how this can happen.

I am using Babel and Webpack in my application, and my intuition is that they are related to the behavior.

- [`instanceof` does work for subclasses of built in classes.](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/caveats/#classes) But `NotFoundError` is subclassing a custom class.
- Webpack seems to have issues if you import the same module multiple times in different ways. However in my application the only module which imports `NotFoundError` is `Foo.jsx`

I think the issue is still Webpack, but cannot find anything on the web that looks related. I'm hoping somebody knows some "gotcha" that I don't.

## Details

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourcePrefix: '\t'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'src', 'node_modules'
    ] // Defining modules prevents the need for relative imports
  },
};
```

Here is the relevant compiled code:

```
var HttpError = function HttpError() {
  _classCallCheck(this, HttpError);
};

var NotFoundError =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_HttpError) {
  _inherits(NotFoundError, _HttpError);

  function NotFoundError(message) {
    var _this;

    _classCallCheck(this, NotFoundError);

    _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _getPrototypeOf(NotFoundError).call(this, message));
    _this.name = "NotFoundError";
    return _this;
  }

  return NotFoundError;
}(HttpError);
var UnauthorizedError =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_HttpError2) {
  _inherits(UnauthorizedError, _HttpError2);

  function UnauthorizedError(message) {
    var _this2;

    _classCallCheck(this, UnauthorizedError);

    _this2 = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _getPrototypeOf(UnauthorizedError).call(this, message));
    _this2.name = "UnauthorizedError";
    return _this2;
  }

  return UnauthorizedError;
}(HttpError);

function getJson(url) {
  return fetchResource(url, {
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        throw new UnauthorizedError(response.body);
      } else if (response.status === 404) {
        throw new NotFoundError(response.body);
      } else {
        return response.text().then(function (text) {
          throw new Error("".concat(response.status, " ").concat(text));
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

// ...

/* harmony import */ var Api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(10);
function _extends() { _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; }; return _extends.apply(this, arguments); }

function _objectWithoutProperties(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded); var key, i; if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) { var sourceSymbolKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source); for (i = 0; i < sourceSymbolKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceSymbolKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(source, key)) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } } return target; }

function _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = {}; var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source); var key, i; for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } return target; }

function Sidebar(_ref) {
  if (profileErrors.length > 0) {
    var error = profileErrors[0]; // `instanceof` does not work here because of either Babel or Webpack

    if (error instanceof Api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["UnauthorizedError"]) {
      return ...;
    } else if (error instanceof Api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["NotFoundError"]) {
      return ...;
    } else {
      return ...;
    }
  }
}
```

Console logs:

[image: NotFoundError logs]

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled output?

Comment: Can you show us your logs? A good and a bad one too pls.

Comment: I've updated the question with the compiled output.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the console logs I'm seeing.

Comment: Next thing you could do is to debug into the code. Put a breakpoint into the compiled code at the console.log statement, and track down the source of the constructor. I suspect you have two separate NotFoundError classes defined somewhere in your application.